# Pure tensorflow implementation of C51

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I have a working implementation of C51 in tensorflow. However, it uses tf.numpy_function which slows down my training loop significantly. I tried rewriting np.add.at using tf.tensor_scatten_nd_add, but unsuccessfully.
I am open to an alternative implementation that does not use np.add.at or rewriting add_to function using purely tensorflow functions.

````
batch_size = 512

v_max = 5
v_min = -5
n_atoms = 51
support = tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(tf.linspace(v_min, v_max, 51), axis=0), tf.float32)
delta_z = (v_max - v_min) / float(n_atoms - 1)

# this is the function I want to rewrite
def add_to(l, u, l_dist, u_dist):
    m = np.zeros_like(l, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(batch_size):
        np.add.at(m[i], l[i], l_dist[i])
        np.add.at(m[i], u[i], u_dist[i])
    return m

# just for the completeness sake
def projected_dist(t_dist, rewards, actions):
    Tz = tf.broadcast_to(support, [batch_size, support.shape[1]])
    Tz = (0.99 ** 5) * Tz
    Tz += tf.expand_dims(rewards, axis=-1)
    Tz = tf.clip_by_value(Tz, v_min, v_max)
    b = (Tz - v_min) / delta_z
    l, u = tf.math.floor(b), tf.math.ceil(b)
    l_dist = t_dist * (u - b)
    u_dist = t_dist * (b - l)
    l, u = tf.cast(l, tf.int32), tf.cast(u, tf.int32)
    m = tf.numpy_function(add_to, [l, u, l_dist, u_dist], tf.float32, stateful=False)
    perjected_dist = tf.clip_by_value(m, 0.0, 1.0)
    null_dist = tf.zeros((batch_size, 3, n_atoms), tf.float32)
    indices = tf.stack([tf.range(0, batch_size, dtype=tf.int32), tf.cast(actions, tf.int32)], axis=-1)
    return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(null_dist, indices, perjected_dist)```
````